# Wildcards in XPath Predicate

Tags: xpath

I am trying to write an xpath expression that would evaluate to a specific substring within ItemInfo

```
<Catalog>
   <List>
      <Item>
        <ItemInfo>
            This describes the Item In which it is listed.
        </ItemInfo>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <ItemInfo>
            This is another item description.
        </ItemInfo>
      </Item>
   </List>
</Catalog>
```

I know I likely need contain() and to use predicates. The string within  will be extremely long and there will a specific substring that I am looking for. I'm not sure how to use a wildcard within the text. Here is my idea of what it may look like.

```
> /Catalog/List//Item/ItemInfo[contains(.,*'another'*)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no wildcards. Just specify the literal substring:

```
/Catalog/List//Item/ItemInfo[contains(.,'another')]
```

Comment: For reference, check out section `4.2 String Functions` of [the official XPath language spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions).